# How to call a native Android constructor in Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How to call a native constructor for an Android class in Delphi XE5?  I want to instantiate a `JWebView` using this constructor - [`WebView(Context)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#WebView%28android.content.Context%29).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
uses
  ..., Androidapi.JNI.WebKit;

var
  MyWebView: JWebView;
begin
  MyWebView := TJWebView.JavaClass.init(SomeContextObject);
  // use MyWebView as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Just a small addition: if an Android class has a default constructor we can instantiate it like `intent := TJIntent.Create;`